# Artemis journal fail leads to artemis failover

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have running Artemis replica set with master and two slaves and having problems with artemis node. It keeps failing time to time. Here is log from failed artemis node:

```
2021-04-14 02:11:15,997 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session ed72f65c-9cb5-11eb-8b65-001dd8b71e33
2021-04-14 02:11:15,997 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session ed72f65c-9cb5-11eb-8b65-001dd8b71e33
2021-04-14 02:11:16,139 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 Id=2 RUNNABLE
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Finalizer" daemon prio=8 Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@47d5008c
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@47d5008c
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:170)
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 Id=4 RUNNABLE
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Notification Thread" daemon prio=9 Id=9 RUNNABLE
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Common-Cleaner" daemon prio=8 Id=10 TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@4912e606
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@4912e606
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    at java.base@14.0.1/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:148)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at java.base@14.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "ActiveMQ Artemis Server Shutdown Timer" daemon prio=5 Id=12 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@4d2d6bfc
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@4d2d6bfc
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
2021-04-14 02:11:16,140 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Thread-0 (-scheduled-threads)" prio=5 Id=18 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@82fec3d
    at java.base@14.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@82fec3d
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
    at java.base@14.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
...
2021-04-14 02:11:16,146 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=AIOSequentialFile:/home/artemis-broker/data/journal/activemq-data-3.amq, message=Timeout on close: java.io.IOException: Timeout on close
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.aio.AIOSequentialFile.close(AIOSequentialFile.java:127) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.aio.AIOSequentialFile.close(AIOSequentialFile.java:104) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.closeFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:534) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.moveNextFile(JournalImpl.java:3214) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.switchFileIfNecessary(JournalImpl.java:3153) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendRecord(JournalImpl.java:2883) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.access$100(JournalImpl.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl$1.run(JournalImpl.java:850) [artemis-journal-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [java.base:]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [java.base:]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]

2021-04-14 02:11:16,151 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] waiting pending callbacks on activemq-data-3.amq from 10 seconds!
...
```

but I can't really understand what is the problem of this issue ? do I have not enough size for journal or something else ?

Comment: It looks like the logging you added was just part of the thread dump emitted when the broker hits an extended delay on a critical path. Could you provide more logging about what the actual problem is? There's not enough information to answer your question at this point.

Comment: @JustinBertram here is the link with more details https://sharetext.me/gf2almovgq It was too large to post it here

Comment: You left out the most important part of the log. I added it back for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most important piece of the log:

```
2021-04-14 02:11:16,146 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=AIOSequentialFile:/home/artemis-broker/data/journal/activemq-data-3.amq, message=Timeout on close: java.io.IOException: Timeout on close
```

This is a "critical IO error" and as such the broker will shut itself down. You should move to ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 as [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3084) was already resolved.

Comment: Than you so much!